# Organize screen/group structure in react navigation v6

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v6

I am trying to migrate an old react navigation v4 to v6 (more than 100 routes).
But I am facing to how to find the best structure to split group of screens in separate file/component.

I have tried this, to move out modals:

```
const ModalGroup = () => (
  <Stack.Group screenOptions={{ presentation: "modal" }}>
    <Stack.Screen name="ModalA" component={ModalAScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="ModalB" component={ModalBScreen} />
  </Stack.Group>
);

export const RootNavigator = () => (
  <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
    <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
    <ModalGroup />
  </Stack.Navigator>
);
```

But is not allowed at runtime with this error:

> Error: A navigator can only contain 'Screen', 'Group' or
> 'React.Fragment' as its direct children (found 'ModalGroup'). To
> render this component in the navigator, pass it in the 'component'
> prop to 'Screen'.

But this is working (but look ugly for me):

```
export const RootNavigator = () => (
  <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
    <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
    {ModalGroup()}
  </Stack.Navigator>
);
```

So what is the best way to structure/organize group of screens in separate files to avoid creating a huge root navigator with all configuration & import ?